# Magento set other order status as default for payment method invoice

Tags: magento

i have question about the order status process logic. magento set an order after set the order as shipped to payed. but i have a payment method "invoice" which allows the clients to pay after recieve the order, so magento set the order state for me incorrect. is there a way to handle that?

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: it's more a solution-related question.
Is there config to achieve it? Or an extension?

I didn't knew that stackoverflow is just for programming related questions. is it?

Comment: Yes, Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A site. Perhaps you should post on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Comment: oh ok sorry, i will post there thanks!
So that's  closed here.